# Access to protected var of Mock class

Tags: scala, mockito

I'm using Mockito to test a scala class with a protected var. I would like to mock this var but obviously I can not access to this var via my mock class.

This is my code:

`abstract class ETL_Generic(val fileCode: String, val rwSessionWrapper: RWSessionWrapper) extends Serializable  {

protected var measurementsByFinalCode: scala.collection.Map[String, Measurement] = _`
}

And this is the code to mock the abstract class:

`val etlGenericMock = mock(classOf[ETL_Generic], withSettings().useConstructor("", rwSessionWrapperMock).defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS))`

How can I assign a value to this var with the mock class?

Thanks.

Comment: Go through `Case-3` of [https://gualtierotesta.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/tutorial-java-abstract-classes-testing/](https://gualtierotesta.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/tutorial-java-abstract-classes-testing/). It should solve your problem.

Comment: It seems like a design issue, why do you need to set the `var` in the first place?

Comment: I have not permission to change the code as it is not mine...I have to do only the test. And with `Case-3` I can not access to the protected var from my mock class.

Comment: The only way I see is to access to this var with getter and setter methods..

Comment: If it is not your code, you should not be mocking it ideally, can't you wrap it in an adapter and then mock the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an adapter extending the class to mock, overriding protected vars and then mocking this adapter.

Thanks!